# jBPM and JPA Transaction Manager: no local transaction to join

Tags: java, spring, jbpm, kie

I'm having a really hard time setting up a jBPM7 project. I'm trying to use the jBPM engine with an H2 in-memory database to make use of the Human Task Service. I've set up my data source, entity manager factory and transaction manager as below:

application.properties

```
...
jbpm.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
jbpm.datasource.username=sa
jbpm.datasource.password=
...
```

JbpmDataConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JbpmDataConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "jbpmDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jbpm.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jbpmEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean jbpmEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("jbpmDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
            .mappingResources("META-INF/Taskorm.xml")
            .packages("org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model")
            .persistenceUnit("jbpm-persistence-unit")
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jbpmTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager jbpmTransactionManager(@Qualifier("jbpmEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

In my resources folder I have a kmodule.xml in resources/META-INF/. All my .bpmn files are in resources/com/mydomain/flow/

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="kbase" packages="com.mydomain.flow" />
</kmodule>
```

I am then creating a runtime engine using the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyRuntimeEngine {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jbpmEntityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jbpmTransactionManager")
    private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public RuntimeManager runtimeManager() {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase("kbase");

        RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder runtimeEnvironmentBuilder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
            .newDefaultInMemoryBuilder()
            .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
            .addEnvironmentEntry(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, transactionManager);
        RuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnvironment = runtimeEnvironmentBuilder.knowledgeBase(kieBase).get();
        return RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(runtimeEnvironment);
    }
}
```

I am autowiring the RuntimeManager bean into another configuration class so I can configure global variables and work item handlers. This then exposes a KieSession bean once it's done. To then start a process, I am autowiring the KieSession into one of my controllers and calling startProcess:

```
kieSession.startProcess(processName, processVariables);
```

which results in the following error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No local transaction to join
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.joinTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.joinTransaction(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:318) ~[jbpm-audit-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.persist(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:246) ~[jbpm-audit-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.afterVariableChanged(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:133) ~[jbpm-audit-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.drools.core.event.ProcessEventSupport.fireAfterVariableChanged(ProcessEventSupport.java:155) ~[drools-core-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.context.variable.VariableScopeInstance.setVariable(VariableScopeInstance.java:114) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.createProcessInstance(AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.java:59) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:260) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.createProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:242) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.createProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:200) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:190) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:185) ~[jbpm-flow-7.22.0.Final.jar:7.22.0.Final]
...
```

How do I properly configure the transaction manager to work with jBPM?

Comment: I think you are trying to do what has already been done. Did you look at the sample springboot projects? https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-samples/jbpm-spring-boot-sample-basic

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same trouble in setting up JBPM 7.x version. Were you able to get JBPM running with JPA transaction manager...from the official documentation it seems that we need external transaction manager implementations like Narayanan or bitronix if JBPM needs to be used in embedded mode